# Next.js redirect from old route to new route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to redirect my application from "/parent" to the "/parent/[parent_id]" path, and I have dynamic parent_id like "/parent/4" and "/parent/12" which has come from the database, but I'm confused about how I can redirect to the dynamic route from the /parent route

old folder structure: "pages/parent",
new folder structure: "pages/parent/[parent_id].js"

```
module.exports = {
    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
              source: '/parent',
              destination: '/parent/[parent_id]',
              permanent: true
            }
        ];
    }
};
```

Comment: You need to explain more of your code and how you render the routes etc for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Yes, I add my folder path also now it's clear or not please check my question again thank you!

Comment: What [parent_id] do you want /parent to get redirected to? As it can only redirect to one path  , so you need to supply a default value to [parent_id]

Comment: parent_id in is numeric like "/parent/123" or "/parent/53434" and parent id is dynamic

this path "/parent" redirect to "/parent/123" or "parent/12345"

Comment: You need to specify the value for `parent_id` in the redirect. You can't redirect `parent` to `parent/[parent_id]` with a random id - it needs to be deterministic.